# What are the examples to understand L-process and R-process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, intuition

R-processes and L-processes
R-process on $ [0,\infty) $ to signify a process all of whose paths 
are right-continuous on $[0,\infty)$ with limits from the left on $(0,\infty)$.     R-function or R- path on $[0,\infty)$ is defined via the obvious analogous definition. 
The L-processes on $(0,\infty)$, all of whose paths are left-continuous with limits from 
the right. 
**How to understnad them in a intutive way**

Answer (score 0):

The R- functions are frequently used for probability distribution functions. 
But if you consider a process, consider for $R$ for example the number of jobs in some factory. It starts with 0 jobs. Then, at some time $t$, a new job arrives. Then, the process makes a jump of size 1 at time $t$. At time $t$, the process has value 1, therefore, the process is not continuous from the left. The function is continuous from the right, since it looks like [this](http://www.ditutor.com/limits/right-continuous.html)
(Most real-world processes will be of this type.)

For an $L$-process, you invert the time axis of the above process.

Comment: how can R process be continuous from the right according to your example

Comment: See link in edit